# Instance in OIC lost public IP

Tags: oracle

I have two instances in OIC free tier.

I saw that I cant connect to either server with SSH.

I logged in to web ui and see both instances running, but they lack Public IP.
These IPs where assigned at instance creation, and I never fiddled with any IP settings.

I dont see anything of value in the logs.

One of the instances have been up and working for months.

Please help

Answer (score 0):

Found this thread:
https://www.reddit.com/r/oraclecloud/comments/u3cc2i/instancevnic_randomly_lost_its_public_ip/

Got one out two instance up & running